# hadoop flume extracting twitter data

Tags: hadoop, twitter4j, flume

I Have used this command while extracting twitter data using flume

[cloudera@localhost bin]$ ./flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f ../conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent

```
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Configuration provider starting
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Reloading configuration file:../conf/flume.conf
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Added sinks: HDFS Agent: TwitterAgent
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Processing:HDFS
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [TwitterAgent]
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Creating channels
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Creating instance of channel MemChannel type memory
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Created channel MemChannel
2015-07-14 05:42:00 [INFO ] Creating instance of source Twitter, type org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
```

It is processing up to this then here is the error:

> 2015-07-14 05:42:01 [ERROR] Unhand-led error
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>       twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StatusListener;)V
>       at org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.configure(TwitterSource.java:119)
>         at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
>         at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:331)
>         at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
>         at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPool Executor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)  2015-07-14 05:44:13 [INFO ] Stopping life cycle supervisor 10 2015-07-14 05:44:13 [INFO ]
>    Configuration provider stopping

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError <- this indicates that you are using the wrong version of twitter4j.

The current 1.6.0 version of flume's twitter-source is built against 3.0.3:

```
[INFO] +- org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.twitter4j:twitter4j-media-support:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.twitter4j:twitter4j-stream:jar:3.0.3:compile
```

just replace your twitter4j libs with those, then it will work.

Comment: hi i am getting below in flume when fetching twitter data to hadoop      2016-09-29 15:55:49,124 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.
Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api